# OSError: Unable to create file (unable to open file: name = '../working/best.hdf5 No such file or directory',

Tags: python, keras, hdf5, resnet

I try to run this code but I have this error :
OSError: Unable to create file (unable to open file: name = '../working/best.hdf5', errno = 2, error message = 'No such file or directory', flags = 13, o_flags = 302)

Please, if anyone had this problem, how you fix it.

Thanks.

```
NUM_CLASSES = 2
CHANNELS = 3
IMAGE_RESIZE = 224
RESNET50_POOLING_AVERAGE = 'avg'
DENSE_LAYER_ACTIVATION = 'softmax'
OBJECTIVE_FUNCTION = 'binary_crossentropy'
LOSS_METRICS = ['accuracy']
NUM_EPOCHS = 10
EARLY_STOP_PATIENCE = 3
STEPS_PER_EPOCH_TRAINING = 10
STEPS_PER_EPOCH_VALIDATION = 10
BATCH_SIZE_TRAINING = 100
BATCH_SIZE_VALIDATION = 100
BATCH_SIZE_TESTING = 1
resnet_weights_path = '../input/resnet50/resnet50_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5'
model = Sequential()
train_data_dir = "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\RESNET"
from keras.models import load_model

model = ResNet50(include_top=False, pooling='avg', weights='imagenet')  # `pooling='avg'` makes the  `ResNet50` include a `GlobalAveragePoiling` layer and `include_top=False` means that you don't include the imagenet's output layer
x = model.output  # as I use `include_top=False`, you don't need to care the layer name, just use   the model's output right away
predictions = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)
predictions = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)
model = Model(input = model.input, output = predictions)
model.summary()
print(model.summary())
sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=SGD(lr=0.01, momentum=0.9), metrics=['binary_accuracy'])
data_dir = "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\RESNET"
batch_size = 32
from keras.applications.resnet50 import preprocess_input
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
image_size = IMAGE_RESIZE
def append_ext(fn):
    return fn+".jpg"
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
train_dir_path = dir_path + '\data'
onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(dir_path) if isfile(join(dir_path, f))]
data_labels = [0, 1]
train_datagenerator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True,
validation_split=0.2) # set validation split 20% versus 80% pour training  

train_generator = train_datagenerator.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(image_size, image_size), 
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE_TRAINING,
    class_mode='binary', shuffle=False, subset='training') # set as training data

validation_generator = train_datagenerator.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir, # same directory as training data kifkif
    target_size=(image_size, image_size), 
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE_TRAINING,
    class_mode='binary', shuffle=False, subset='validation') 
from tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint
cb_early_stopper = EarlyStopping(monitor = 'val_loss', patience = EARLY_STOP_PATIENCE)
cb_checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath = '../working/best.hdf5', monitor = 'val_loss',    save_best_only = True, mode = 'auto')
fit_history = model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=STEPS_PER_EPOCH_TRAINING,
    epochs = NUM_EPOCHS,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=STEPS_PER_EPOCH_VALIDATION,
    callbacks=[cb_checkpointer, cb_early_stopper])
model.load_weights("../working/best.hdf5")
```

Comment: Show us your file structure.

Comment: thanks for this answer but what do you mean with file structure? here you have all the code. Thanks

Comment: I mean the relevant file and directory layout. It's likely somethings in the wrong place

Comment: Looks like you don't have the right path for that `best.hdf5` file.  Only you can figure out where that file is!

Comment: Thanks. Please, where I can found the right path best.hdf5 ?

Answer (score 0):

The path in `ModelCheckpoint`, cannot be reached: `../working/best.hdf5`

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem myself. My filepath ended in `.h5`.  I removed it and then it worked!

Try changing this

```py
cb_checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath = '../working/best.hdf5', monitor = 'val_loss',    save_best_only = True, mode = 'auto')
```

to

```py
cb_checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath = '../working/best', monitor = 'val_loss',    save_best_only = True, mode = 'auto')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try:

```
cb_checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath = 'working/best.hdf5', monitor = 'val_loss', save_best_only = True, mode = 'auto')
```

or try:

```
cb_checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath = 'working/best.h5', monitor = 'val_loss', save_best_only = True, mode = 'auto')
```

Answer (score -1):

Use full absolute path instead of '../working/best.hdf5'